# Reverse a string in 0.10

Tags: rust

I'm having trouble reversing a string in the newest version of rust, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975102/how-do-i-reverse-a-string-in-0-9) post but I'm still getting some errors. I'm trying to reverse a string and compare the two without any luck:

```
fn is_palindromic(num: int) -> bool {
    let num_str = num.to_str();
    let rev_num_str = num_str.chars_rev().collect();
    if rev_num_str == num_str {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

then I receive the error:

```
main.rs:8:28: 8:39 error: type `collections::string::String` does not implement
any method in scope named `chars_rev`
main.rs:8       let rev_num_str = num_str.chars_rev();
```

Comment: BTW, you don't need to allocate a whole new `String` to compare: you can use [`std::iter::order::equals`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/iter/order/fn.equals.html) to compare two iterators directly: `equals(num_str.as_slice().chars(), num_str.as_slice().chars().rev())`. (Also, I have a feeling you're not using 0.10 if you have the `String` type defined, are you using master/a nightly?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the traditionally useful string methods are defined in the [std::str::StrSlice](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrSlice.html) trait. To get a slice from a `String` value, you can call the [as_slice](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_slice) method. It looks like `chars_rev` is no longer defined in the `StrSlice` trait, but there is a `chars` method which returns an iterator [Chars](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html).

This particular iterator implements the [DoubleEndedIterator](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) trait, which means it can be reversed by calling `rev`. That should be all you need:

```
fn is_palindromic(num: int) -> bool {
    let num_str = num.to_str();
    let rev_num_str: String = num_str.as_slice().chars().rev().collect();
    return rev_num_str == num_str;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", is_palindromic(12321));
}
```

Note that I also added a type annotation to `rev_num_str` since the compiler can't infer its concrete type (`collect` is polymorphic and can build [many different kinds of "container" values](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html)). You could alternatively instantiate `collect` specifically:

```
let rev_num_str = num_str.as_slice().chars().rev().collect::<String>();
```

Comment: thanks! What is the use of `collect()` in these cases though?

Comment: It consumes an iterator into a container. In this case, the container is a `String`. But you could also use `Vec<char>` to get a vector of characters instead of a string. Remember that the `rev` method returns an iterator, so it has to be consumed in some way to check for equality. (@dbaupp's suggestion will avoid the allocation of a new container like `String`.)

Comment: I guess this is a good first approximation. For completeness one should probably normalize the string so that graphemes are represented using a single code point (if possible). Unicode is complex and I can't say I'm fully aware of all its intricacies.

Comment: @sellibitze, in this case, the string always consists of just `-0123456789`, I.e. there's no need to handle codepoints/normalisation/semantic reversing. In fact this could be implemented more efficiently using byte iterators.